# Merging different codes in a single one

Tags: python

I have multiple files with different codes for the same program. For example:
File 1 has program function and utility
File 2 has GUI code
File 3 has saving pattern and closing functions

How can i merge them in one single big code?

I'm new in python, i've tried to paste one after another but didn't work

Comment: You need to post a [mre] showing what you tried and explain how it failed.

Comment: It sounds like your code is nicely organized right now -- why do you think you need to merge it into one big file?

Comment: Right -- your master file just uses `import` to bring in the others.

Comment: I'm trying to build a video observation software, something like ofop but more usable, I'm new to python and I can't write a full stacked code so I'm trying to build different part and then merge all together. First I would build the ui, then the functionalities. But idk if I must merge them in some specific order or not